# Creating a testing enviornment to test fixes without duplicating entire site

Tags: iis, web, webserver, windows-server-2003, symlink

I have a rather large site with hundreds of files and a footprint of many hundreds of mgs.  I have in a place an assignment system that we utilize to work on enhancements and bug fixes.  What I'd like to do is setup a system in which each assignment gets pushed to the web server (testing server) in it's on "sandbox".

Typically I'd just create a copy of the site under a virtual directory, replace the files affected by the assignment and proceed with testing.  Problem here is we would be making many copies of massive amounts of files.

What I have in my head would be a system where a "master" copy of the site contains all the current files (presumably from source control).  From there create a virtual directory for each assignment with symbolic links to all files and folders except for those actually changed for the assignment.

I essentially want to create a integrated build process that will create the virtual, pull the sym links from master and then replace the links of the files that changed with the actual changed versions from the assignment.

Is this a possibility with Windows Server 2003 and IIS?

Answer (score 0):

Probably possible, but sounds like a nightmare.  Must all of these files be copied to each testing site?  If they are merely content files (htm, gif, jpeg, etc), leverage VDIRS to a common location.  It can even be a network location.

Comment: no, unfortunately it's pretty much all dynamic (asp, asp.net)